# How can i install Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll in GAC

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dll

I've made a project with c# in which I use **"Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll"** as a reference assembly.
When I install my program on another computer it gives me an error message:

> unable to run the application requires that assembly
>   microsoft.data.schema.sql.unittesting version 12.0.0.0 in the global
>   assembly cache

How can I install this `.dll` in **GAC** using code.

Comment: Why does your program need this assembly? It's an assembly used for unit testing and should probably not be needed by your production code.

Comment: It's generated automatically when I added a database.

Comment: So anything I can do to publish the project without need of it?

Comment: You could try to remove the reference, rebuild your solution and try if the program runs on your machine.

Comment: It worked !!
Thanks very much,

Comment: Great, I promoted the comments to an answer. Could you please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it? It's good for my reputation B-) as well as for the SO ecosystem.

Comment: Rebuild worked OK but it didn't work on the target's machine !

Comment: Did you get an error? If so, what was it? If not, what does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: Yeah , removed it from application files and it worked, thanks again , i will accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assembly is used for unit testing databases. It's shouldn't be needed by your production code.

Remove it from your project references and try if the solution still builds and, if so, the program still works on both your machine as well as on another machine.